# Making a main screen in Ursina

Tags: python, ursina, mainscreen

I am currently making a game with Ursina and i've been struggling to find a code to make a Main-Starting-Screen to start the game or show controlls.

Here is my game code:

```
game = Ursina()

ground = Entity(model = "untitled.blend", texture = "Soul Sand.jpg", scale = 400, collider = "mesh")

player = FirstPersonController(model = "player.blend", position = (-6.39844, 148.284, 62.5471),jump_height = 7, jump_duration = 0.5, speed = 10, texture = "Player Texture.jpg", collider = "mesh")
camera.z = None

health_bar = HealthBar(bar_color=color.lime.tint(-.25), roundness=.5, value=100)

def input(key):
    if key == "shift":
        player.speed = 25
    elif key == "control":
        player.speed = 10


house = Entity(model = "House.blend", texture = "Tree Texture.jpg", scale = 2, collider = "mesh", position = (0, 146.3, 15))

tree = Entity(model = "Tree.blend", scale = 15, texture = "Tree Texture.jpg", collider = "mesh", position = (15.5488, 140, 55.0674))

game.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try just displaying a quad model which is a 2d square

```
Menuback=Entity(model="quad"scale=(10,10))
```

and just make
Allother entities to .enabled=False
And the menu to true
Create a button
And onclick menuback.enabled =False
And the rest od entities set on true
Here is the ursina docs if u need to look at some stuff

https://www.ursinaengine.org/api_reference.html